# Wondeting what the highlighted part of the sentence below means

Tags: word-meaning

> People receiving aid after Texas **fertilizer plant** blast.
>
> Source:
> http://english.people.com.cn/102774/8215433.html

I am wondering what it is and how it blasts.

I read this and I was ashamed not being able to explain this sentence in my native language while talking to my friend.

A million thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

A fertilizer plant is a factory that produces fertilizer and produces chemicals to supply to farmers.
[Fertilizer Plant http://media.courierpress.com/media/img/photos/2013/07/18/Fertilizer_Plant_Expa_inev_1_t607.jpg](http://media.courierpress.com/media/img/photos/2013/07/18/Fertilizer_Plant_Expa_inev_1_t607.jpg)

Like many factories there are safety issues... They contain many chemicals and have flames/ other things that make it liable to blast or explode. So basically the story was that a factory that produces fertilizer in Texas exploded and affected many people.

Answer (score 0):

'Plant' in this case refers to 'manufacturing plant' or 'factory'. The word is used generally for high-output factories.

As you were referring to 'what and how it blasts', it could be ammonium nitrate:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonium_nitrate

It has popular use both as an industrial fertilizer and as an explosive, so it could very well be what caught fire, accidentally.